# Logging "overhead" best practice?

Tags: logging

In the piece of Software im looking at there is something like this:

```
string message = "loggging" + getsomedata + "text" + getsomemoredata + ...;
DBLog(LOGLEVEL_HIGH, message);
```

DBLog takes some more data, puts it all together and passes it to a "loggingservice"

This is for a very high loglevel, which will only be set in some very (!) rare debugging scenarios. On a example system the function containing this code is called about 25 times per second on average.

I think it might cost a little performance, as this is called everytime even if the logging is off. What is the way to go here? Try to get to the current loglevel somehow and only call all this only if needed? Just let it stay like this? Something completely different?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally your logging code should determine if and when to log.  Unfortunately that requires your code that is about to log something to always construct and make the call to the logging code.  There is the option to expose from our logging layer a method to determine if the log message would be logged to determine if you should construct the message.

ie:

```
  if( DBWouldLog(LOGLEVEL_HIGH) )
  {
         string message = "loggging" + getsomedata + "text" + getsomemoredata + ...;
         DBLog(LOGLEVEL_HIGH, message);
  }
```

Comment: It does determine that itself. The code you posted is what i meant with "Try to get to the current loglevel somehow and only call all this only if needed". But my question is basically if that makes any sense at all or if there is a better way

Comment: I thought you were worried about log message creation cost... not the cost of logging.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the language support. Most notably in my mind is the support of macros or perhaps inline functions.

If you are using language with built in macros like C++ (or C which your code does not look like), then you can define your macro as something like (assuming C/C++ macros) this:

```
#define DBLog(level, message)                 \
        do {                                  \ 
            if (DBWouldLog(level)) {          \
                DBLog_output(level, message); \
        } while (0)
```

Your `DBWouldLog(level)` could be simple macro (or similar inline function)

```
#define DBWouldLog(level)    (level < DB)
```

This would eliminate the function call that you seem worried of costing performance.

Note that even if your language of choice does not support macros, you can still easily support macros by first preprocessing your source files with macro system of choice (I have seen C preprocessor used for processing Java code and have personally used `eruby` in another context to provide more powerful preprocessing layer). At least if you are using make files, it is very easy to implement the required additional rule.